# Who need to do the Garuda Purana pooja?

Tags: garuda-purana

Who all need to do or read the Garuda Puranam pooja.
What all are the instructions that we need to follow while doing, and after doing that. What age people can to do this.
What is the purpose of Garuda Purana .

Answer (score 1):

Not much is said on this topic as it concerns the delicate topic of death. This might answer some of your questions:

> What is the significance of Garuda Purana after death?
>
> Sri Sri Ravi Shankar: Garuda Purana is all about the life after death.
>   How the soul goes, where, what and all that. There is only certain
>   time when you are supposed to hear that, (the few days after the soul
>   leaves the body) listen to it so you know where the departed soul goes
>   and what happened to them. There are a lot of things in Garuda Purana.

http://www.artofliving.org/2-august-2011-qa-1